# how to make measure that shows deviation

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table which shows sales depending on the source (fact and forecast).

| year | week | category | sales rub | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 32 | shorts | 54387 | 2021 fact |
| 2021 | 32 | shorts | 58264 | forecast |
| 2021 | 33 | dresses | 4325 | 2021 fact |
| 2021 | 33 | dresses | 5432 | forecast |

When I make a matrix in powerBI  need to get a deviation fact from forecast, bu I cannot make a quick measure division because in fact i have only one column with values. How can i calculate the deviation? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If using powerquery, load data

click select source column

transform .. pivot column ... and for values column, choose sales rub from dropdown

[image]

add column .. custom column. Name it deviation with formula

```
= [2021 fact]-[forecast]
```

full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[source]), "source", "sales rub", List.Sum),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "deviation", each [2021 fact]-[forecast])
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: does that work for you